# IDE for desktop development in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, ide, desktop

Hey I'm aware this question isn't very technical, but I'm new to the Delphi language and I'm wondering what IDE would be great (preferably free) for a beginner with C# and Java experience? I've heard from google that Delphi XE is a good place to start, does anyone have a different opinion on other IDE's available (advantages and disadvantages).

Thanks, appreciate the help.

Comment: Delphi is an IDE already. Relatively recently they renamed their `Object Pascal` language dialect to "Delphi". Dont ask why, marketing or accessibity reasons. After clarifying this mess a challenger appears - [Lazarus IDE](http://lazarus.freepascal.org/) for Free Pascal compiler.

Comment: "Relatively recently," @Downvoter? It was nearly a decade ago.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The nearest thing of Delphi language that you can get outside of Embarcadero's Delphi IDE, AFAIK, is Lazarus. It is constructed on the same base language Delphi was, (Object Pascal), but as RRUZ has already said, is not the same. Anyway, link. http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/

Comment: One huge advantage over Delphi and Prism/Ogygene+VS: Lazarus is open and Free. You can just load the IDE in itself as an example project. Can't do that with Delphi or Visual Studio. Also, the IDE itself is available for Linux, OSX and Win32/64.

Answer (score 16):

The only IDE for the Delphi language is the [Embarcadero Rad Studio IDE](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi). and 
there is not free versions of this IDE only a `Starter` version.

Comment: Thank you, is the majority of commercial development completed with the Rad Studio IDE?

Comment: Now starter is free...

Answer (score 4):

Yet another Delphi language is Delphi Prism which is an object Pascal variant which targets .net. You can develop Visual Studio and MonoDevelop.

Comment: Embarcadero removed Delphi from Prism. From now on the name is Embarcadero Prism [version]. As the compiler is based on Oxygene (another "fork" of Object Pascal), I think it was a wise decision. Explanation: http://blogs.remobjects.com/blogs/jim/2011/09/02/p2975

Comment: @EMBarbosa: Agreed, this' really a wise decision.

Answer (score 2):

lazuras free pascal is ide for development delphi app and it is free